# how to create other sizes of original image in one go wordpress uploads

Tags: posts, uploads, images

I want to create all possible other size images in one go for all my original images.May be possible my question is not fine but I have a question so I am asking here.

I have original image in my uploads/2016/06 folder named "dummy.png" but when I check wp-admin post it is not showing image so I checked in console and src is uploads/2016/06/dummy-300*300.png and this image is not available.

Similarly I have so many original images but dont have their other sizes images created by wordpress.I don't know how and who deleted other images but this is what I have now.How can I solve this?

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix, to use plugin: **Regenerate Thumbnail images**.
Try that, it might help.